# Practical example of architecture using EBC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, architecture

I was intrigued by Robert Martin's talk about ["Architecture: The Lost Years"](http://confreaks.net/videos/759-rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years).  In it he discusses the Entity, Boundary, Control design pattern on which MVC is based.  I love the idea of deferring architectural decisions.  He described deferring the decision about how to implement the DB layer in his own wiki app FitNesse.  I have organically deferred decisions like this in my own coding, though there wasn't a preconceived modular design that brought this about.

I want to better understand this EBC architecture (which seems closely related to DCI) from a practical standpoint so that I can begin using in a small project.  I want to capitalize on "deferring decisions" and the ability to swap out aspects of the design like the UI.

Rails, for example, uses a form of EBC (MVC) but it's so heavily baked in that one could not easily substitute an alternate UI thus converting a Rails app to a console app or a desktop app.  The intriguing thing about design for me is this ability to transform applications by swapping one thing out and plugging another in.  That is, I wonder at the idea of designing an architecture so that one can, in a manner of speaking, swap out the UI or the persistence layer.  I feel that if the architecture is well designed, the coupling will be low, and such a feat will be within grasp.

I've ordered [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201544350) by Ivar Jacobson that Bob mentioned in his talk.  I've search online quite a bit but all of the examples I've found show simple diagrams.  I speak code.  I would benefit more from looking over a few simple classes that demonstrate the concept and show how one might swap out one layer (UI, DB) for some other implementation through the use of boundary classes.

If someone can't point me to a good resource illustrating this, would this be hard to whip up?  Maybe we could use the standby example used in lots of software books: a video rental store (almost a relic these days).  Please demonstrate how the UI or DB layer could be swapped.  One thing that's confusing me is views.  I can't tell from the diagrams I've seen if the views are the boundary classes themselves or if they just communicate with them.  Also, Bob mentioned that the original intent of EBC was that we'd have lots of micro-views not a single macro-view (as we do in typical MVC); I'm curious what this might look like.  (I prefer Ruby or JavaScript but, as beggars can't be choosers, any example would be fine.)

Thank you.

Comment: Rails is mostly model and controller; replace render and redirect with versions that accepted "txt" and "gui" formats you're basically done--actions only need a params hash. Just need additional handlers, and a less-HTTP-oriented routing/command definition system, although the current one could be co-opted by assuming request types are command modifiers. In the Java world things are decoupled like this all the time.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  I'm not after any sort of Rails retrofit.  I just want to know some practical ways I might implement EBC in a greenfield app.

Comment: I understand; I'm simply saying that making Rails do that wouldn't be the Herculean effort it appears at first. But this is a pretty nebulous question--as long as the layers are separated, it's all pretty straight-forward. What, precisely, are you looking for, and what would constitute a "successful" implementation?

Comment: (And as long as this is tagged w/ Rails and Ruby, people may make an assumption that it's tagged that way for a reason :)

Comment: I am looking for practical experience with separating business logic from actual implementation.  There are hundreds of todo apps.  Almost all of them could not easily have the persistence layer or the gui layer replaced.  Imagine I write the app as a web app backed by a MongoDB.  Later, I want to reduce the app to a console app with a text file persistence layer.  Most all apps don't have the design to easily allow for this sort of thing.  I want to learn to design in this manner.

Comment: Hmm. My experience has been different, although I make things pretty decoupled by default. In fact my last few apps have had a CLI interface (for testing and for the higher-level QA folks) and a few included a Swing interface for administration. (Haven't done any non-DB datasources, although that's a matter of DAO changes, and doesn't change how I'd design it). What do you perceive is holding you back from being able to do this, or what do you see as the reason "most all" apps can't do this?

Comment: I'll tell you what; if I have time this weekend I'll dig out an old project and see if I can convert it into a simple TODO app w/o much thought and put it on github--not guaranteeing I'll have time, but if you ping me next week I'll update you.

Comment: I saw the talk and ordered the book too.  Am very interested in seeing some examples in ruby.

Comment: "Most all" apps can't do this because the developers base their coding on assumptions about "what the app is" and not "what the app might be".  As such the GUI and DB logic are generally baked in (tightly coupled).  If the developer later decides he wants to extract his "web app" core into a "console-based client" the extraction of reusable code is arduous.  Even if the layers were kept separate the preconceptions about what the app is shape the core use cases.

Comment: While there is no practical example in this article, I found the diagram and explanations very helpful : 
http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Comment: Also, this article is interesting - it sounds like doesn't actually have an example - or doesn't want to share the example if he has it : http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2011/11/22/Clean-Architecture.html

Comment: I think DHH disagree with this kind of separations.
http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/test-induced-design-damage.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I understand the video by Uncle Bob using "EBI" (**Entity**, **Boundary**, and **Interactor**) you should completely decouple your business behavior/state from frameworks/OS and services.

So in case of an Rails app your business behavior/state is completly free of dependencies to the *Rails* framework and hence can be tested like with rspec without firing Rails!

So on the business side you have **Boundary** classes wich interact with the Rails side using request and response models (very simple dataholders, not to be exchanged with the usual models from *Rails*). Only the **Boundary** classes interact with the **Interactor** classes which implement the (business) use cases / scenarios. And only the **Interactor** classes interact with the **Entity** classes which encapsulate the business state.

On the *Rails* side you find **Controller** classes interacting with **Boundary** classes (using Request models) and backwards a **Boundary** class interacts with a **Presenter** (using a Response model). Only **Presenters/Controllers** interact with Views (with the help of models (again simple data-holders). Note that in the realm of *Rails* **Presenters** are most likely **Controllers**.

Where does this leave AR? Well AR just provides the persistant service. On the same level as the **Presenter/Controller** level you will find **Service** classes which provide their services to the **Boundary** classes. So they provide all the necessary services which are frameworks/OS/technology dependent like persistance, security, timing, notifaction, etc..

With this architecture you are really able to reuse your business logic and completely replace the UI or database technology. For example, porting to mobile (iOS, Android, Windows) should be pretty straight forward.

With *Rails*, your **app folder** could look like:

```
app/
    controllers/    Only these interact with Boundary classes
    models/         simple data-holders, no AR here! (see services)
    views/  
    services/       AR-stuff
    boundaries/     To be tested without Rails
         models/    Request & Response
    interactors/    use cases / scenarios, to be tested without Rails
         entities/  "the real business model without technical dependencies"
```

With this architecture, you need to code a bit more but don't forget the benefits of a good architecture:

1. A good architecture allows major changes to be deferred
2. A good architecture maximizes (major) changes not made

Last note: compared to the MVC pattern, its more like the M is replaced by EBI, the C can be splitted in CP/resenter), and an S(ervice) is added. So this could be called: VCPS/EBI but that sounds ugly to me ;-) BEPVICS maybe?

**@Seralize**, thanks for your feedback.

Let me try to answer your questions, so far I understand them: the stuff in services are coupled to Rails. They provide the implementation for the logic in EBI side. In the usecase of security, you have to be clear what (quantified) requirements you have, so you know what logic you can implement on EBI side, for instance (business) rules about when a user(role) has access to what content(and needs to be authenticated).

This means to implement authentication will be implemented using Rails, this service will be used by EBI. This security related logic in EBI is then pretty easy to reuse in your Java GUI example. There you have only to reimplement the authentication service.

**To be clear in the security example:**

The EBI side has the logic: what stuff needs what kind of security and when and how. The Rails knows nothing about this, it request what to do from the EBI side and or the EBI side request the Rails side to act.

The Rails side only implements the way how to do security like asking the user to authenticate (when needed) and passing the result of this to EBI so the logic can decide what should be done next.

> EBI demands both sides to be decoupled & independent. It were as you
>   are developing the EBI as a library with a defined API.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the part about services? Are the services coupled to Rails? Assuming they are, then how is the application behind the boundary decoupled when things like security is left in the Rails framework? Where would the "is the user logged in?" kind of functionality reside? If not hidden behind a boundary, then it wouldn't come along with the app itself when for example writing a Java GUI with pure command-line interaction. You give a really good explanation anyway, keep it up :)

Comment: Hi Seralize, pls see the edited post for a reply.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, by coupling the framework to the application, isn't that basically going against the architecture Uncle Bob is suggesting? One of the key points is to stay decoupled from the framework aswell, not only the database etc. By implementing security in Rails and not in the application itself it is prone to logic security errors and the like when changing framework. However, one could just use an HTTP API to communicate to the Rails app from the Java side, but that takes away the point of ECB. It would then become "Rails with encapsulated domain logic in the model"

Comment: And again see update above. But to reflect on your HTTP API comment: no, introducing an extra protocol does not help. You write Rails in Ruby and why not write EBI in Ruby as well? Only EBI doesn't contain Rails specific code. Wish I could help writing example code with Rails but I am afraid I am to busy writing iOS apps in Ruby using Rubymotion.com :)

Comment: But that's what I'm hinting at. If you implement the security or anything else on the Rails side you're coupled to Rails.

Comment: You don't implement "security" in Rails, you implement may be a logon service, which is being used by the EBI side...

Comment: Authentification is a good example for something that could be implemented on both sides: It makes sense to have the login service on the EBI side if you have a highly collaborative app where multiple users interact with each other. On the other side, if you have a one-man note-taking app authentification is only necessary because of the delivery mechanism web. The native desktop app doesn't need a login at all. In this case it seems natural to have authentification on the Rails side. In some cases the EBI doesn't even need to know about multiple users.

Comment: To achieve a decoupled Entity from ActiveRecord, there're a solution called Datamappify (https://github.com/fredwu/datamappify). This Gem able to create repositories to your entities using Virtus to map them.

Answer (score 5):

Ask and you shall receive.  I kept my eyes open and discovered this resource by Avdi Grimm:

http://avdi.org/devblog/2011/11/15/early-access-beta-of-objects-on-rails-now-available-2/

In it, he covers some of the reason that Rails projects get so tightly coupled to both the framework and ActiveRecord.  He uses TDD to assure loose coupling with techniques like

- Dependency Injection
- Presenters
- Strategy Pattern
- DCI

It provides a good start to answering this question in a practical way.   (It costs $5 for the early beta but will eventually be free.)  In fact, it's the first resource I've found that does.  Please add any others you find.

Here's the real gem that elucidates the heart of the problem:

> One day, after years of witnessing and addressing the technical debt incurred in various maturing Rails codebases as a result of ActiveRecord-inspired tight coupling, I had an epiphany. What if we stopped treating ActiveRecord as the backbone of our model classes, and instead, programmed as if ActiveRecord were merely a private implementation detail?

Corey Haines puts it another way:

> I pull the behavior out of my models into other objects that wrap the models.
>   I prefer to make the AR objects simple wrappers around the db-access stuff in AR.
>
> I have a fairly strict rule that controller actions cannot use AR finders or,
>   in fact, interact with AR at all. AR should be accessed within api methods
>   inside your model, not from the outside.

Comment: I've been working through Avdi's book and I would say that he doesn't exactly do what Robert Martin is suggesting.  He does do some decoupling in that he does not load rails in his unit tests and I defers the use of active record and persistence for as long as possible, but in the end his example app is still very coupled with active record.

Comment: @ChristianSchlensker I concur with your assessment :-) For better or worse, OoR shows some baby steps towards decoupling, not the full decoupling espoused by Uncle Bob.

Answer (score 2):

This should be of interest too. It's the other book, not referred to by name in ["Architecture: The Lost Years"](http://confreaks.net/videos/759-rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years)

"Agile Software Development: Principles, Patterns, and Practices", by "Uncle Bob" Martin.

Taken from this [SE question & answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149658). Read the [other answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149657) too.